# How to create a download link when opening a file from local file system

Tags: html, filesystems

We are shipping some docu stuff on a cd and to have a better overview over all the files, we want to provide an index of all files as html, that can be put on the cd. The idea is that the user can download the wanted files just like from any webpage.

The problem is, that I can open the pdf in the browser but i want the download dialog to pop up if i click the button so I added the `download="some-name.pdf"`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <base href=".">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="files/test.pdf" download="some-name.pdf">Download file</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Using this via webserver (http) seems to work, but I cannot get it to work from the local file system...

To reproduce, just store the snipped in a file, create a folder "files" next to it and put any pdf file with an `.html` extension and name it `test.pdf`. Then open the page in a browser like Chrome or FireFox. (I am on a mac, but i guess it is the same for Windows or Linux?!)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but I am running Chrome 79 or FireFox 72 - they are both supposed to support it for quite a while...

Comment: Above code is working fine. Can you explain about your issue?

Comment: @AarthiA I thought i did explain my issue. `The problem is, that I can open the pdf in the browser but i want the download dialog to pop up if i click the button.`
Do you see the download dialog? What operating system do you use?

Comment: Yes, i can see the dialog. I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS .